# Network flow - does edge lie on directed path

Tags: graph-theory, network-flow, directed-graphs

a) Let $f$ be a flow network $(G, c, s, t)$ and $e$ an edge such that $f(e) > 0$. Then there must exist a directed path from $s$ to $t$ that contains the edge $e$.

b) Let $f$ be a flow network $(G, c, s, t)$ and $C$ a cut in that network. If for all $e \in C$ is true that $f(e) = c(e)$ then $f$ must be a maximum flow.

Is a) and b) true or false, if so why?

My arguments that a) is True:

If $f(e) > 0$ and no path from $s$ to $t$ would contain that edge, then we would break Kirchhoff's laws.

b) I'm not really sure how to argument on that one. But I think it's false because $C$ can be any cut.

Comment: What do you mean by Kirchhoff's laws? I didn't find anything relevant about this in the internet at first glance. For b) try to use the max-flow-min-cut theorem.

Comment: You definitely need some more detail for your answer to a). You can decompose a flow into directed paths (and cycles). Take such a path, and reduce the flow along it to zero. Repeat this until all such paths have 0 flow. If $f(e)>0$ still, then we get a contradiction by max flow min-cut, since we have 0 flow at the sink, but we have a cut with positive flow.